# python replace not na value

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I want to create a new column and replace `NA` and not missing value with `0` and `1`.

```
#df
col1  
1      
3

5

6
```

what I want:

```
#df
col1   NewCol
1           1
3           1
            0
5           1
            0
6           1
```

This is what I tried:

```
df['NewCol']=df['col1'].fillna(0)
df['NewCol']=df['col1'].replace(df['col1'].notnull(), 1)
```

It seems that the second line is incorrect.
Any suggestion?

Comment: `df['NewCol']=df['col1'].notna().astype(int)`

Comment: @WeNYoBen `TypeError: data type not understood`

Comment: @PeterChen use it as a string: 'int'. or use numpy data types too: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['NewCol'] = [*map(int, pd.notnull(df.col1))]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to convert all 'na's into '0's. How you do this will vary by scope. 
For a single column you can use:

```
df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].fillna(0)
```

For the whole dataframe you can use:

```
df.fillna(0)
```

After this, you need to replace all nonzeros with '1's. You could do this like so:

```
for index, entry in enumerate(df['col']):
    if entry != 0:
        df['col'][index] = 1
```

Note that this method counts 0 as an empty entry, which may or may not be the desired functionality.